# Which one better for virtualization for multiple OS

Tags: virtualization

I want to test multiple Operating Systems on one PC. Which one of these is better for virtualization of multiple OSs?

1. VirtualPC
2. Windows 7

Comment: Why is this tagged `osx` ? Do you want virtualization solutions for a Mac OS X host (e.g. VMware Fusion, Parallels, etc) ?

Comment: It depends on what OS you're running the VM from, what type of VM you want to run (hypervisor vs paravirtualization), and whether you want a system that is easier to use or has better performance.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that the Windows 7 built-in virtualisation is [primarily for allowing older, incompatible Windows applications to run under later versions](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) seamlessly.

If you want virtualisation of multiple OS' (where *multiple* doesn't just mean Microsoft SomethingOrOther), I'd be looking at a product more targeted as that.

I actually prefer VMWare Player but any of them should be good enough:

- VMWare.
- Virtual PC.
- VirtualBox.
- QEmu.
- Bochs.
- even DosBox if you're emulating really *old* operating systems.

That's also my order of preference if you're interested. You're probably not, and it's a matter of taste anyway so feel free to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is in OS X, I'm assuming you want something that runs ON OS X.  I'd recommend Virtualbox.  It's free and works well.

Comment: I find my battery doesn't last too well on Macbook Pro; but it is free and easy to use.
Note that upgrading to newer versions of VirtualBox can cause Vista guest OS's to think they're no longer genuine!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try out OS X in a virtual machine on your Windows 7 PC: stop thinking about it. There ARE ways to accomplish this, but none of them are legal.

If you are still interested you should stick to Virtual Box and google around a bit =)